# Virtual thread for reading InputStream from HTTP response

Tags: java, inputstream, nonblocking, thread-local, java-21

With the java 21 one can convert a blocking IO code to non-blocking one by just executing it in a virtual thread.

Should I simply wrap the HTTP call that returns an `InputStream` (as in method `nonBlockingA`), or would it be more efficient to also perform the reading and deserialization of the `InputStream` in a virtual thread (as in method `nonBlockingB`)?

In other words, is the reading of `InputStream` a blocking IO operation?

Keep in mind that the response could be quite large, potentially containing more than 500,000 Strings.
I'm also not sure if the used libraries are using any ThreadLocals, which is not recommended with virtual threads

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class Request {
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
    private CloseableHttpClient httpApacheClient;

    List<String> nonBlockingA() throws Exception {
        InputStream bigInputStream = executorService.submit(this::getResponse).get();
        return deserialize(bigInputStream);
    }

    List<String> nonBlockingB() throws Exception {
        return executorService.submit(() -> {
            InputStream bigInputStream = getResponse();
            return deserialize(bigInputStream);
        }).get();
    }

    private InputStream getResponse() throws IOException {
        return httpApacheClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://random/names/size/500000")).getEntity().getContent();
    }

    private static List<String> deserialize(InputStream body) throws IOException {
        try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(body, UTF_8)) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(reader, List.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using virtual threads does not make code non-blocking, it just means that the carrier thread is available to do other work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok, you are right. But my question still remains. Which method is better/

Comment: All the methods are blocking, because you are calling `get()`. Wrapping al that (or using an excutor that uses virtual threads) doesn't make it suddenly non-blocking. If you want it non-blocking yuo need to use a `CompletableFuture` throughout your stack. As Mark said if you use a virtual thread the actual platform thread will be able to do other work.

Answer (score 5):

There is no significant difference between your variants. Any method returning a fully constructed result, like a `List<String>`, is always a synchronous or blocking method, as there is no way around waiting for any required result of asynchronous or external evaluations, to construct the final result.

Asynchronous methods have to return a `Future` or similar kind of promise object which allows them to return before the actual result has been computed. This requires the caller to be able to deal with this kind of result. When the caller has to return a fully constructed result to their caller, it brings you back to square one, as it again requires a blocking wait.

So this traditional asynchronous processing requires all processing steps to be implemented as asynchronous operations, chaining callbacks to defer the actual computation to when the inputs are available.

The point of [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) is that they do not require you to write such traditional asynchronous methods at all. You can write your operation in a synchronous way. To stay at your example,

```java
List<String> straightForward() throws IOException {
    try(InputStream bigInputStream = getResponse()) {
        return deserialize(bigInputStream);
    }
}
```

It’s the *caller’s responsibility* to invoke your code within a virtual thread, to get the benefit. Or, maybe it’s better to say that it’s the caller’s choice to use your method just synchronous or within a virtual thread. But it’s also possible that the caller uses your method in a plain synchronous way but the caller’s caller arranged the call in a virtual thread.

In the best case, 99% of your code does not deal with threads or asynchronous APIs but is written straight-forwardly in a synchronous manner. Only the remaining 1% has to arrange the invocations in virtual threads, like the web server creating a virtual thread per request or such alike.

Comment: Let's suppose I'm the caller of the code and the goal is to not keep the carrier thread busy with my IO. I'm OK with blocking code and don't mind to wait for the .get() to return.
Since deserialize method is not IO (?) , the question is, should it be executed in  avirtual thread or not. Especially if it might use some thread locals. So maybe, it is better and safer just to call getResponse on a virtual thread to free the carrier thread and then continue the work on InputStream with the carrier thread

Comment: This makes no sense. If you suspect the operation to block a carrier thread, there is no point in starting it in another virtual thread where it would block a carrier thread too. You are over-complicating things. If the underlying I/O operation has been adapted, it will release the carrier thread and there is nothing to worry about. If not, it will block a platform thread one way or another and there’s nothing you can do about it. Likewise, you can not change the fact that an actual computation has to run on a platform thread on a CPU core. So just use the straight-forward synchronous form.

Comment: Its not about avoiding blocking, but efficient utilization of carrier threads, by executing IO operations in a virtual thread and let other requests use the freed carrier thread.

Comment: And what if Gson used ThreadLocal (Jackson does), then calling the code in a virtual thread from outside would create a memory leak if deserialization would happen in a virtual thread, wouldn't it?

Comment: It’s the other way round. If your code uses thread locals and doesn’t clean them up, you have a memory leak with conventional thread pools. When you use a virtual thread per request, all thread locals will definitely die at the end of the request processing. And again, you are over-complicating things. There is nothing to gain from starting another virtual thread for the I/O operation.

Comment: I don't use a virtual thread per request. The rest of the code is not using virtual threads at all

Comment: Then, as said, you won’t get a benefit from virtual threads. The only way to get a benefit, is by using them in the intended way. In either case, whether your calling threat is virtual or not, there is no benefit in starting a new virtual thread in this situation. Your approach is like, after hearing that a van is better than a trolley, putting all stuff into a van and try to pull it like a trolley.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not really using virtual threads yet, but try to understand how they work and when to use them and avoid memory leaks because of thread locals. I should have created an example where the methodB would fetch 100 websites in parallel and combine them into one single return value. Then maybe virtual threads would make more sense, right?

Comment: Yes, running 100 fetch operations in virtual threads makes sense. The “one virtual thread per fetch” approach is similar to the “one virtual thread per request” of the web server example. The code to initiate all fetches and wait for the result is the 1% of the code having to deal with with virtual threads while the code to do the actual fetch operation can be written like synchronous/blocking code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then lets say I'd use jackson for de-serialization, which is not yet loom-friendly. Would it be better to collect 100 large InputStreams and read them one by one outside of virtual threads or is there no benefit doing so, as reading an InputStream is IO and we have no choice but wait until jackson gets rid of thread locals?

Comment: Use the simplest implementation possible, as that’s what this feature is all about, the ability to write simple code. Keep in mind that 3rd party libraries (usually) settle on the JDK methods which have been adapted or will be adapted by the JDK team soon, so the ability to release the carrier thread on I/O is already there, even if the 3rd party library has not been adapted. Regarding the thread local variables, don’t overestimate their impact. It’s only a performance issue, if any, so try and measure…